# Random Variable: Independent or Dependent?

Tags: probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, random-variables

> You are given two independent random variables X and Y, where
>
> Pr(X=0) = Pr(X=1) = Pr(Y=0) = Pr(Y=1) = $\frac{1}{2}$
>
> Define the random variable Z = X*Y
>
> Are the random variables X and Z independent or dependent?

I know for the random variables to be independent, it should follow that:

P(X=x ^ Z=z) = P(X=x)*P(Z=z)

In this case, taking X and Z at 0:

Pr(X=0 ^ Z=0) = $\frac{1}{2}$ * $\frac{1}{2}$ = $\frac{1}{4}$

I calculated the probability of Z by considering there is a 2/4 probability of Z=0. Not confident about that.

Pr(X)*Pr(Z) = $\frac{1}{2}$ * $\frac{1}{4}$ = $\frac{1}{8}$

For Pr(Z) I got $\frac{1}{4}$ by multiplying the probabilities of Y and X at 0.

Since, $\frac{1}{4}$ not = $\frac{1}{8}$ they are not independent.

Did I approach this correctly?

Comment: How did you get $\Pr[Z = 0]$ (as well as $\Pr[X = 0 \land Z = 0]$)? This does not look quite right (although your approach seems fine to me).

Comment: $(X,Y) = (0,0), (0,1), (1,0)$ all yield $Z = 0$, so $P(Z = 0) = 3/4$, not $1/2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the distribution of $Z$. First, it can only take the values $0$ and $1$. But as $\{Z=1\}$ is equivalent to $\{X=1\wedge Y=1\}$, then $P(Z=1)=\frac12\cdot\frac12=\frac14$ and so $P(Z=0)=\frac34$.

Also check that
$$P(Z=0|X=0)=1,$$
and since $P(Z=0)\neq 1$, this implies $X$ and $Z$ are not independent, because knowing that $X=0$ modifies the probability of $Z=0$, that is
$$P(Z=0|X=0)\neq P(Z=0).$$

Comment: I'm a little confused on how to calculate P(X=1 ^ Z=1). I know P(Z) = 1/4 based off that there is only one instance of (x,y)=(1,1) from 4.

Comment: Well, actually you should use conditional probability. $$P(X=1,Z=1)=P(Z=1|X=1)\cdot P(X=1).$$

Comment: Do I calculate the conditional probability like this:

We need to find Z=1 with event X=1. So, (x,y): (0.0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1). So there is a 1/4 probability that Z=1 with X=1?

So, P(X=1 ^ Z=1) = 1/4 * 1/2 = 1/8?

This doesn't seem right as it then becomes independent

Comment: No, if $X=1$, the only possible cases are two: $(1,0)$ and $(1,1)$. And only the last one gives $Z=1$. So $P(Z=1|X=1)=\frac12$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $XY$ cannot be $1$ when $X$ is $0$. However $X$ may be $0$ and $XY$ may be $1$.